# MVC C# CRM - One app many organizations

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, crm

We've developed simple CRM application in ASP.NET MVC. It's for a single organization with few user accounts.

I'm looking for easy way to make it work with many organization. May I use `ApplicationId` from Membership provider for this? Every organization would have they own `ApplicationId`.

But this means that every row in the database would have to have `ApplicationId` too, right?

Please give you suggestions. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: In the first place, why do you call it "ApplicationId", not "CompanyId" or "OrganizationId". Apart from that,  yes - you'd probably have one more table for companies and you'd have to use "CompanyId" in your tables. But this will mix all the data.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, for the "easy way" you already missed the bus. Since the easy way would have been to make this possible already by design. It would have not been that much of a burden to include the `OwnerId` to the data already in the first phase and make your business logic to work according to that.

Currently the "easy way" is to refactor all your data and business logic to include the `OwnerId`. And while doing it, look ahead. Think of the situations "what if we need to support this and that in the future" and leave some room there for the future by design. You don't need to fully implement everything right now but you'll find it out how easy it is to make your application scale if it was designed to scale.

What comes to the `ApplicationId`, that's an internal ID for your membership provides to scope your membership data per application. I would stay away from bleeding that logic to the whole of your application. Keep in mind that authenticating your web users and assigning them in roles and giving them rights through roles is a totally different process than ownership of data.

In ASP.NET MVC, you would use `[Authorize]` attribute to make sure that certain actions can or cannot be performed by certain users or groups while determining which data is whose, should be implemented in the data itself. Even if you would run two or more instances of your application, it'd still be the same application. So `ApplicationId` doesn't work here for scoping your data.

But, let's say your CRM would not be so small after all in the future and it becomes apparent that either your initial organization or one of the later ones would like to allow their customers to log on and check their data, you would need to build another application for the customers to log onto. This site would use a different `applicationId` than your CRM. Then your client organization could map the user accounts to their CRM records so that their customer could review them.

So, since your CRM is (still) small, the easiest way is to design a good schema for your `clients` to be stored in and then mark all your CRM data with an `OwnerId`. And that `OwnerId` cannot come from the users table, or membership table or anywhere near there. It has to come from the table that lists the legal owners of the data. Whether you want to call them Organizations, Companies, Clients or whatever. It cannot be `userId`, `roleId`, `applicationId` etc, since users might be leaving an owning organization, roles are shared between the organizations (at least the ones that are used to determine access to certain MVC actions) and `applicationIds` are meant for scoping membership and roles between different kinds of client applications.

So what you are missing here is the tables describing owners for the CRM records and mapping all the data to their owners. And for that there's no easy way. You already went on developing the CRM thinking "this is just a simple one-organization CRM so let's make things the easy". Now you're having a "simple multi-organization CRM and asking an easy way to recover from that initial lack of design. Next step would be asking how you make your "not so simple multi-organization CRM" to easily do something you didn't take in to account in the first place.

The easy solution is to design your application scalable and doing "just a little" extra to support future growth. It'll be much easier in the long run than to spend a lot of extra rewriting your application twice a year. Also, keep in mind. It's a CRM after all, and you can't go ahead and tell whoever is using it in their business that have a day off since we're fixing some stuff in the CRM.

I'm not patronizing you here. I'm answering to anyone who might be reading this to stop searching for easy solutions to recover from inadequate planning. There isn't any. And seeking one is making the same mistake twice.

Instead, grab some pen and paper and plan a workable design and make it work. Put some extra effort in the early stages of software design and development and you'll find that work saving you countless hours later in the process. That way, whoever is using your CRM will stay happy using it. It'll become easier to talk to your users about future changes while you don't have to think "I don't want to do that since it'd break the application again". Instead, you can enjoy together brainstorming the next cool step. Some of the ideas will be left for later but some room for implementation will be designed already on this stage so that the actual implementation year later will come in smoothly and will be enjoyable for all the parties involved.

That's my easy solution. I have 15 years of development behind and the fact that I'm still enjoying it to back the above up. And it's mainly because I take every (well most of them anyway) challenge as an opportunity to design the code better instead of trying to dodge the inevitable process. We have this old saying in Finland: "Either you'll do it or you'll cry doing it". And it fits the bill here perfectly. It's up to you if you like crying so much and take "the easy way" now.